# Importing "Visible range Volume Profile" indicator in my pinescript

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api

There is an indicator called "Visible range Volume Profile"  in tradingview. I want to use its attributes like VAL(low volume), VAH(High volume) in my pinescript strategy. I am not able to find any way to include it in my script.Please help.

I tried following methods:

1. Including the indicator by "import vrvp" in my script.

[image: Adding indicator through script and error]

2. By adding the indicator on my script from the candlestick chart. but it didn't work.
   [image: Adding indicator through chart]
   [image: Selecting indicator]
   [image: Error message]

Comment: Also tried <import PineCoders/volume/5 as vol> and import TradingView/volume/5 as vol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately it can't be done.

1. You can only import libraries. The way you tried it above is correct though.
2. Some scripts cannot be added on top of other indicators. I don't know any particular details to this restriction but it's a general rule.
3. Unfortunately this volume profile script is a proprietary tradingview script, which means you cannot even see the source code so that you could alter it the way you need it.

Your best chance is to look for something similar, but open source among the community scripts and while respecting a license conditions and credentials, alter it the way you need it.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I appreciate it. I tried to search for a similar script, but couldn’t find it. I also tried developing it. I just need POC, VAH, and VAL for support and resistance.